# How properly annotate hibernate entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, entity, hibernate-mapping

Write some usual tests for my MVC webapp and stopped at findById() testing.
My model classes:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private double purchasePrice;

    private double retailPrice;

    private double quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "supplier_id")
    private Supplier supplier;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products;

@Entity
public class Supplier {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToOne
    private Contact contact;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany
    private List<Product> products;
```

And my test code:

```
private Product productTest;
private Category categoryTest;
private Supplier supplierTest;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    categoryTest = new Category("Test category", "", null);
    supplierTest = new Supplier("Test supplier", null, null);
    productTest = new Product("Test product","", 10, 20, 5, supplierTest, categoryTest);

    categoryService.save(categoryTest);
    supplierService.save(supplierTest);
    productService.save(productTest);
}

@Test
public void findById() throws Exception {
    Product retrieved = productService.findById(productTest.getId());
    assertEquals(productTest, retrieved);
}
```

Well, assertion failed, because of difference product.category.products and product.supplier.products properties, as you can see on pic:
[image]
One product have it as null, another as {PersistentBag}.
Sure I can easy hack it by writing custom equals method (which will ignore these properties), but sure it's not the best way.

So, why these fields are different? 
I'm sure solution in properly annotation of entities fields.

Answer (score 1):

Two pointers :

- you use `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` in your relationship  fields, so fields with that annotation are dynamically loaded by your ORM when you retrieve your entity while entites created in your fixture of your unit test are created outside from your ORM and you don't value these fields.
- Even if you remove `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)`, you may have other differences if you want to do assertEquals() with a retrieved entity and a entity created by the hand. For example, with Hibernate, your lazy `List` will not be `null` but instance of `PersistentList`.

So, you should perform some works to perform assertions.
You may check properties individually or you may use Reflection to assert fields and ignore comparison for null fields in the expected object.

check http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html, it may help you.